# seaborn kdeplot error: "No contour levels were found within the data range"

Tags: python, seaborn, contour

I am using the seaborn PairGrid function. I have two datasets that I have been trying to plot on the same PairGrid. My diagonals are normalised `plt.hists`, my lower diagonals are `sns.scatterplot` and my upper diagonal is `sns.kdeplot`. However, some of the kdeplots are producing this **user warning**:

> /home/user_xyz/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py:1184: UserWarning: No contour levels were found within the data range.

- This is what my PairGrid looks like with the error - as you can see for some of the `kdeplots` the red data is missing and this is what is throwing the warning:
  [plot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Izo.jpg)
- However, interestingly enough, when I plot the red data (which is the missing one) separately, the `kdeplots` work out just fine! There is no warning. This is what it looks like individually:
  [red data PairGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZaCI.png)
- Some other things I have noticed are: increasing `bw_adjust` makes the issue worse and decreasing the `bw_adjust` removes the issue but instead of getting a proper looking contour plot for my red data I get many tiny circles instead

I thought this might be due to the fact that the distributions are not peaked and are therefore not Gaussian like but that still doesn't explain why separately the red data plots fine or why the blue data plots fine on the PairGrid despite having the same flat distribution as the red data.

Does anyone know why I am unable to properly plot the `kdeplots` for both datasets on the same PairGrid? Or why this error is occurring?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I've added the code I use down below and have included some toy data that closely resembles the real data (the real data is private). It is in the form of a Google sheet (access should be given) which can then be read in using Pandas. Sorry if this is inconvenient - I have a very large dataset and it isn't stored in a database.

*Code:*

```
# data variable contains data inside the linked Google sheet
g = sns.PairGrid(data, hue = "Type")

plt.figure()
g.map_diag(plt.hist, alpha = 0.7, density = True, histtype = 'step', range = [-1.05, 1.05], bins = 20, linewidth = 2)
g.map_upper(sns.kdeplot, hue_order = ['Ch', 'Si'])
g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, hue_order = ['Ch', 'Si'])
g.add_legend()

for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        g.axes[i, j].set_ylim(-1.1, 1.15)
        
for i in range(5):
    g.axes[i, 0].set_xlim(-0.1, 1.0)
    
for i in range(5):
    g.axes[i, 1].set_xlim(0.5, 1.0)
    
for i in range(5):
    g.axes[i, 2].set_xlim(-0.2, 1.1)
    
for i in range(5):
    g.axes[i, 3].set_xlim(-0.2, 1.2)
    
for i in range(5):
    g.axes[i, 4].set_xlim(-1.2, 1.3)

plt.show()
```

*Data:*

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KtX8nZU8ghe55xIEfE5e-srhWqWb5ZPS4G02gRVT-o8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Would it be possible to add some minimal code? Preferably including some toy data which reproduce the problem. Possibly the red data is too small compared to the blue data.

Comment: @JohanC thanks for replying :) I've edited my original post to have the code and data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sns.kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) has an option `common_norm=` which defaults to `True`. That reduces the two sets relative to their number of elements. As one set is much smaller than the other, it gets so small that it won't be drawn together with the other.

Both sets can be shown at "full" size using `g.map_upper(sns.kdeplot, hue_order=['Ch', 'Si'], common_norm=False)`. Alternatively you can set a lower threshold: `g.map_upper(sns.kdeplot, hue_order=['Ch', 'Si'], thresh=0.02)`.

Note that `common_norm=False` makes the `kdeplot` with separated hues more similar to the `kdeplot` without using hue.

Here is a comparison between the different options for `kdeplot`, using toy data with a similar difference in set sizes:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

M = 30
N1 = 50
N2 = 2
data = pd.DataFrame({'Variable4': np.concatenate([np.random.randn(M, N1).cumsum(axis=0).ravel() / 2 + 10,
                                                  np.random.randn(M, N2).cumsum(axis=0).ravel() + 20]),
                     'Variable5': np.concatenate([np.random.randn(M, N1).cumsum(axis=0).ravel() / 2 + 20,
                                                  np.random.randn(M, N2).cumsum(axis=0).ravel() + 10]),
                     'Type': np.repeat(['Ch', 'Si'], [M * N1, M * N2])})

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(18, 4))
sns.kdeplot(data=data, x='Variable4', y='Variable5', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Not using hue')
sns.kdeplot(data=data, x='Variable4', y='Variable5', hue='Type', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Default with hue')
sns.kdeplot(data=data, x='Variable4', y='Variable5', hue='Type', common_norm=False, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('hue, common_norm=False')
sns.kdeplot(data=data, x='Variable4', y='Variable5', hue='Type', thresh=0.02, ax=ax4)
ax4.set_title('hue, thresh=0.02')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparison plot]

Comment: Thank you - it works great now with the `common_norm = False`. I just have a question regarding axes. I am changing my axes titles using `g.axes[i, j].set_xlim` and `set_ylim` but it seems I can't change the axes of each graph in my PairGrid individually - but rather everything in the same column or row has to have the same set of axes. Is this true?

Comment: About the diagonal, it seems`sns.PairGrid()` has default `diag_sharey=True`, so you can change that if needed. For the other subplots, I think there isn't any sharing of axes.  To keep the sharing on the diagonal, you might add a test `if i != j: g.axes[i, j].set_ylim(...)`

Comment: Hi again, I was hoping to ask your advice on a related error I get when using `common_norm = False`. For one particular dataset, when I have this parameter I get the error `ValueError: Contour levels must be increasing`. Do you know what might cause this? Could it be something to do with some the values being negative?

Comment: A kdeplot only works with positive values, how can they be negative? Could you create an example with toy data with this error? Or maybe one of the sets has no elements?

Comment: So originally this error was coming when I was plotting two datasets on the one PairGrid. I have tried plotting just one of the datasets on the PairGrid and the same error comes up. I've uploaded the data that causes this error to a Google spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pJzbYBLYuD9HncnuI281j4G4ek7XKqJ7qc9wFw027BA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem seems to be that your 'variable2' and 'variable4' are almost linear dependent. And that seems to generate some error somewhere. If they were perfectly linear dependent, the error would be `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Matrix is not positive definite`. In general, linear dependent columns can't generate a meaningful 2D kdeplot. But it still seems to be a bug in seaborn that the code ends with a crash.

Comment: Hi, yes the bug is strange. Thanks for your help! It works now when I remove one of those two variables (either Variable2 or Variable4).